# Connect teradata JDBC driver on coldfusion 11

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion, datasource

I tried to install TERADATA JDBC on ColdFusion 11 using [this](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/ColdFusion11.html) link.
Everything is fine, but when I try to create the datasource, I get following errors:

> "Connection verification failed for data source: TeraJDBC4
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver available for TeraJDBC4,
>   please check the driver setting in resources file, error:
>   com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver The root cause was that:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver available for TeraJDBC4,
>   please check the driver setting in resources file, error:
>   com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"

ColdFusion Class Path: C:\td\tdgssconfig.jar, C:\td\terajdbc4.jar

I am using ColdFusion 11 and WAMP web server. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the connection string you used when setting up the datasource?

Comment: It looks like the ColdFusion cannot find the Teradata JDBC Driver files. Is your ColdFusion classpath entry correct and that it points to both the jar files?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting, is due to the missing driver from ColdFusion repository.

You need to place the jdbc driver jar file(s) at \ColdFusion11\cfusion\runtime\lib\ and restart ColdFusion 11 Application Service.

Do check, if the DB you are using, is supported with ColdFusion 11 or not [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf).